# Checking if JSON Key exists in REST method

Tags: java, json, rest, post

I'm implementing a REST API and want to check if a key exists in the JSON formatted request that passed through my POST method.

I'm looking for something along the lines of `jsonobject.haskey` type of method. So far I've come across Jackson and json-simple libraries but lot of the information on them seem outdated and I'm having a tough time navigating.

My goal is to take in a JSON formatted POST request to create an instance of a resource. Depending on the existence of the key in the JSON object, values will be assigned through setters.

If you can direct me to a library as well as an API and few examples, it'd be very helpful.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

would be processed as

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "option":,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

because `JSON.hasOptionKey` failed.

Comment: You should post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to have some kind of contract between the JSON request payload and domain objects, obviously you can manually parse the json with some simple JSON parsing library, but it is error prone.

Using something like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), you can represent your JSON structure with a Java object and vice versa, for example:

```
class X {
    String id;
    List<String> values;
}
```

will serialize to something like:

```
{"id": 3, "values": ["1", "2", "3"]}
```

you can then also set the options for the (de)serialisation so the parser knows how to handle nulls, for instance, if `id` is missing in the java object, the JSON will be

```
{"values": ["1", "2", "3"]}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of usage with GSON (imports and getters/setters removed for brevity):

```
public class Question42529415 {

    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            //.serializeNulls()
            .create();

    private static Item fromPost(String postRequestJson) {
        return GSON.fromJson(postRequestJson, Item.class);
    }

    private static String toClient(Item item) {
        return GSON.toJson(item);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clientReq = "{\n"
                + "    \"id\": 1,\n"
                + "    \"name\": \"A green door\",\n"
                + "    \"price\": 12.50,\n"
                + "    \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]\n"
                + "}";

        Item item = fromPost(clientReq);
        System.out.println(item.getName() + " " + item.getOption());

        item.setOption("modified option");
        String modified = toClient(item);
        System.out.println(modified);
    }
}

class Item {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String option;
    private double price;
    private List<String> tags;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if below makes sense? 1) set Post method to take in gson as an argument, 2) Implement a serializer class and call it inside POST method, 3) within the serializer class, set options for the deserialization in order to handle nulls, 4) return the JSON object converted to string which then gets passed to my service to set correct values in my model

Comment: @viviboox3, sounds right :) see my update with an example